How to make LLM more accurate in code review?
I have been trying to get LLM to help with code review but it is not going well.
I want the LLM to be able to spot potential errors in the code or even give suggestion on optimization.
None of the LLM I test were able to solve a pretty simple case (gpt-4, o1, claude, qwen…)
Here is the sample code in PHP:
echo $data->status?->id == 4 ? "member1" : "non-member1";
echo !empty($data->status->id) && $data->status->id == 5 ? "member2" : "non-member2";

tldr: LLM should tell me 2nd sample is safer but it is doing the opposite
I tried:
# first attempt 
what is the difference between these code samples?
first sample: {{sample1}}
seconde sample: {{sample2}}

# first response (which is false btw)
The first sample is safer as it handles the case where $data->status might be null.
The second sample does not handle the case where $data->status might be null and will throw an error in such a scenario.

# my reply (then LLM agrees)
it seems you are wrong about the second sample, you said "Throws error if $data->status is null."
but the function 'empty' of PHP also check if the data is set, right?

# second attempt 
I have these code samples.
define the concept and functions used.
give me the difference between the samples.
first sample: {{sample1}}
seconde sample: {{sample2}}

# response is more elaborate but in summary same wrong response as before


Have you consider tools like PHPStan? https://phpstan.org/
